# can any clutch be used with the DMF or must there be a "dual mass clutch"?

Tags: clutch

can any clutch be used with the DMF or or you required to use a "dual mass clutch" as advertised by retailers>

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Use the proper parts otherwise you get to take it apart again.

Some have changed to a solid flywheel and clutch which worked for some but not all, they got to replace with dmf after...